# How to get current timestamp in php?

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to insert the current timestamp to mongodb in PHP. I wrote the following code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
echo $end;
```

I get the following output:

> 0.00000000 1379320378

Now I have two questions:

1. This code is right?
2. How can I get the output like:

> 1290932238757

Comment: `date('U')."".date('B')` ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodate.construct.php if you check this link, the output is correct !!

Comment: I think you're looking for the `time()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output is a Unix Timestamp concatenated with Swatch Internet time

```
$timestamp = date('U');
$swatch = date('B');

$now = $timestamp.$swatch;
echo $now; // 1379320935404
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/2Lv6kjHp)

Comment: Why did you add an empty string between `date('U')` and `date('B')`?

Answer (score 1):

The `MongoDate` object consists of two propeties and this is what you see when you `echo`, you actually see the string serialisation of the object in the form of the `usec` property. To get the result you want you can do:

```
$end->sec
```